# blue screen of death on win10 dell xps13 9350 DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, crash

My laptop is 1.5 years old (dell XPS 13 9350), a couple of weeks ago I got a blue screen of death, and ever since then the frequency increases (now ~3 a day).

The stop code is: DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

what failed:  bcmpciedhd63hd.sys

I installed the latest drivers etc, nothing has changed... 
where do I even start? (google was not helpful regarding bcmpciedhd63hd.sys but I assume it is related to the hard drive?)

EDIT: using sfc didn't find any violations

Comment: Does your computer have the killer network drivers? I got the same thing for a while and then eventually just changed me network drivers to generics instead of the killer drivers and it worked.

Comment: what are the killer drivers ?

Comment: it's a network card

Comment: what's the name of the killer driver?

Comment: You determined which driver failed by using windbg I presume?  "I assume it is related to the hard drive?" - It does not.  The driver has nothing to do with a HDD.  *The driver belongs to your network device.*

Comment: no, I have no idea about windbg...

Comment: First thing to try is to let Windows repair any OS file issue using SFC and DISM. See https://www.howtogeek.com/222532/how-to-repair-corrupted-windows-system-files-with-the-sfc-and-dism-commands/

Comment: sfc came out fine... no violations etc...

Comment: @bla It’s the best tool to diagnose the cause of your issues.

Answer (score 1):

That is the Broadcom network driver. I would do one of two things. Either download the latest from Dell's support page or go in to Device Manager and un-install and remove the driver then reboot and let it find it again.

Comment: did that , so far so good

Answer (score 1):

I had similar Blue Screen of Death's with the error message `RQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` (as well as other seemingly motherboard-related issues) at irregular times with my XPS 10 9350 with a QHD touchscreen. Also, the keyboard and mousepad would fail and stop working quite often, requiring a reboot, after which everything was back in working order.

The issue proved to be related to the Dell DW 1820A Wi-Fi adapter (which is just rebranded hardware from Broadcom). I replaced it with an Intel Dual-Band Wireless AC 7265. This completely resolved my issues regarding the Blue Screens, Keyboard and touchpad.

If you plan on exchanging your network card, make sure to download the appropriate drivers beforehand, and to delete the obsolete drivers after you exchanged the hardware. I found that the old driver conflicted with the new one.

Replacing the card requires a Torx (not *Torq*) screwdriver. Disconnect the antenna connectors *carefully*, replace the cards, then reconnect the antennae *carefully*.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Super User. Thank you very much for your answer. In the future, please try to focus on facts ("Replacing the old card resolved the problem for me") and less on personal opinions ("Dell cards are garbage. Intel is superior!").